# failed to use data-name to match array although it should match

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a

list, a data-name will be attached to it which matches the value of the list for example

```
<li data-name="hello">hello</li>
```

i also push several parameters into an array
so for example
var array =[];
array[0] = a:hello b:goodbye c:seeyou

so right now what i want to do is
1) click on li to retrieve data-name value which is "hello"
2) check the "hello" against the array for another element "hello"
3) if match, get the index position and delete that index from the array
(as the value "hello" in

is called out from a element in the array, that why i want to detect the exact index in array which contain the element "hello" when i clicked on the

and remove it when i press delete)

This is the code i used to match

```
found = $.inArray($(this).attr("data-name"), array);
```

which i placed in

```
            $(".li").click(function(){
                alert("data name is " + $(this).attr("data-name"));
                found = $.inArray($(this).attr("data-name"), array);
                alert(found);
                alert("name of element is " + array.a);
            });
```

As i said before, when i append the

list i have make it so that the data-name is the same as the value in it.

Using the above code i have successfully retrieve a matching data-name "hello" and element "hello" as well but my found returns me -1 which means it didn't match. Any idea why it didn't match when both my alert turns out to be matching? Thanks

Comment: where are you pushing these items in your array? Can you debug the code and make sure that "hello" is in the array?

Comment: i have a submit button in a form, when i press submit i push it into the arrays, alert("name of element is " + array.a); is actually checking for "hello" in the array and it returned positive..

Comment: If `array.a` works, I don't think `array` is an array at all. what does `array[0]` return?

Comment: How are you adding items to the array?

Comment: it returns a:"hello" and other elements, i can confirm it's an array since i'm calling the elements in it for other uses as well such as appending and stuffs. i'm wondering if data-name can actually be used to checked against an array element at all

Comment: @caspian array.push(new Info("hello", "goodbye", "tomorrow"));

Comment: Gotcha - see my updated answer.

Comment: @caspian i think i know why, .inArray only matches the index, so if you are comparing hello with [0] = hello, it will match. But mine are being pushed in with a lot of parameters so my [0] = a:hello, b:goodbye, that why it didn't match? Do you have any idea how i can match hello with one of my many parameters that contain the word "hello?

Comment: yep - with grep - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array variable contains an array of objects, you can't search for "hello" you need to find the object where `object.a == 'hello'`

for this you can use grep (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

```
$(function() {
    var array = [ { a: "hello", b: 'there'} , { a: "world", b: 'hi'} ];
    var stuff = 'hello'; // <- this can be $(this).attr("data-name")
    var found = $.grep(array, function(n) { return n.a == stuff; });

    // found will be a list of results - we only want the first one
    if (found.length == 1) {
        alert('found: ' + found[0].a);
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQat2/3/

UPDATE: 
For clarification `grep` takes in an array and a function, the function must perform a comparison, which will happen for each element in the input array. Grep returns all the items that the comparison succeeds for. In our case it will return all the elements that have its `a` attribute `== stuff`. this is where `$(this).attr("data-name")` should go in your code.

In your case I assumed that each `a` item would be unique, so I check that the results are 1 and if so, we display the name that was found for the first element.

Comment: can you explain how the function works? I would like to also understand what the code is executing, so i can know how to use it in future.. and also add in a code that it will relate to the index of the word found and delete it for my reference if you may. Thanks!

Comment: can i assume var found = $.grep(array, function(n) { return n.a == stuff; }); function(n) means if it found something it will be [0].a, if my length put 2 and in the array there are 2 hello, it will be [0].a, [1].a increment each time hello is found and store into found which is an array now? Thanks

Comment: instead of showing the results of found[0] storing the whole index element, how can i make it show which index in 'array' contains that element 'hello'?